# C program, getting cartesian coordinate from degrees of rotation

Tags: c, math

I have been working for too long on the business applications it seems... And graduated too long ago perhaps :) Recently i have been tasked writing a small simulation of robotics using C (although this question is more math/algorithm than C) where i have two units (tank-bots) starting at an X and Y coordinate on a playfield.

Now there are keys on a panel to rotate them, and a key to move them forwards. I am now facing a minor brain meltdown on the translation from degrees of rotation to the next X,Y coord to move to in the cartesian playfield.

Due to limitations in HW only fixed point is available for the actual movement, but calculations can be done by float values.

I wrote the following code just from memory just now:

```
/* Recalculate to radians */

int radians;



/* Use sin and cos to get a vector (new x and y coords). Translate from polar to   
   cartesian coordinates */
radians = (int) _tanks[0].rotationAngle * (M_PI / 180);
_tanks[0].x += _tanks[0].speed * cos(radians);
_tanks[0].y += _tanks[0].speed * sin(radians);

radians = (int) _tanks[1].rotationAngle * (M_PI / 180);
_tanks[1].x += _tanks[1].speed * cos(radians);
_tanks[1].y += _tanks[1].speed * sin(radians);
```

Unfortunately it seems my brain is not really refreshed on polar coordinate math and geometry after all these years on writing pure biz software, so it seems to not work as intended.

For instance if rotationAngle is 180, instead the next x/y is to the left, causing the bot to topple over :)

What i want is a movement scheme similiar to the old Micro Machines games if you remember where the next point would be in front of where the object is facing, so it moves (speed) number of steps there.

Can someone suggest where i'm going wrong here...

Also, if there is a smoother way of doing this in C than the pure mathematical attempt that i just wrote (badly at that), give me a hint.

EDIT:

Tried to add :

```
 float radians;


 radians = (45 - _tanks[0].rotationAngle) * (M_PI / 180);
 _tanks[0].x += (int) (_tanks[0].speed * cos(radians));
 _tanks[0].y += (int) (_tanks[0].speed * sin(radians));
```

according to answer below as 0 degrees is indeed the positive Y-axis. But this also gives incorrect results. Now movement for 180 degrees starting point is upwards to the left. At 180 degrees should be movement along the negative Y axis.

Some more code:

Init of _tank struct -

```
tanks[0].acc = 0;
tanks[0].dec = 0;
tanks[0].rotationAngle = 180;
tanks[0].speed = 0;
tanks[0].x = 400;
tanks[0].y = 150;
tanks[0].turretRotationAngle = 180;
```

The rotation degree is just a number (fixed integer), and i wrap it around as according to the circle @ 360 degrees, like so -

```
switch(direction) {
case 0:
    tank->rotationAngle -= degrees;
    if(tank->rotationAngle < 1) {
        tank->rotationAngle = 360;
    }
break;
case 1:
    tank->rotationAngle += degrees;
        if(tank->rotationAngle > 360) {
        tank->rotationAngle = 0;
    }
break;

}
```

One key for rotating clockwise, one for counter clockwise.

The rotation works, but the movement does not, as described...

Results of debug run:

Initial state (no movement due to 0 speed) -

```
radians = -2.3561945
x = 400
y = 150 
speed = 0
```

After movement (speed > 0) -

```
radians = -2.3561945 (the same since i only press the move button)
x = 399
y = 149 
speed = 2
```

This seems odd. The X coord should not change at all if the rotation is 180 degrees from the initial origin right? Only the Y should change, and in the opposite direction. I would translate the change instead to if speed is 2, vector length should be 2 so change would be 2 steps in the direction the object is facing, so y = y + 2 and x = x + 0 for 180 degree rotation on the object?

I feel like i'm getting there :)

Further EDIT:

Seems to be ALMOST correct along the lines of what i need for the playfield if i do this:

```
 radians = (_tanks[0].rotationAngle - 90) * (M_PI / 180);
```

Note -90...

Still when speed is lowered it seems to glitch but at least it moves in the right direction.

Comment: `radians` is going to be a number between 0 and 2PI, i.e. 0 to 6.28. Therefore radians must be a float.

Comment: With a rotation angle of 180 the next x/y should be to the left. What did you expect? cos(180 deg)= -1, sin(180 deg)=0.

Comment: ... and that seems to be the only functional problem with this code. You might also consider a `double` since `M_PI` is one.

Comment: Single-step the code and look at the value of `radians`.  An `int` value isn't going to work very well, as @user3386109 already noted.  If you can't single-step, add `printf()` statements to see what the values are during the computation.  When you know what the values are it will help you figure out why the code isn't doing what you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For instance if rotationAngle is 180, instead the next x/y is to the left, causing the bot to topple over :)

Yes, that is what your code does: your code is correct, aside from the `int radians` issue that [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) mentions above, provided that 0° is the positive x-axis, 90° is the positive y-axis, 180° is the negative x-axis, 270° (or -90°) is the negative y-axis.

I'm guessing that instead, you want 0° to be the positive y-axis? And — do you want 90° to be the positive x-axis (so your angles proceed clockwise around the circle), or the negative x-axis (so they proceed counterclockwise)? For the former (clockwise) case, just change `_tanks[...].rotationAngle` to `(90 - _tanks[...].rotationAngle)` (to "flip" around the 45° line); for the latter (counterclockwise) case, just change it to `(_tanks[...].rotationAngle + 90)` (to "rotate" it 90° about the origin).

Comment: Tried to change it as below, but not working still... Adding some more code to the question.

Comment: radians = (_tanks[0].rotationAngle - 90) * (M_PI / 180);

This appears to give the movement along the right path i need, however it glitches a bit when transitioning in speed... But it is now along the path of the objects as desired... Just by experimentation though, i have to much af a shady memory of this subject to remember why -90 would be the right value to align to.

Comment: @RichardEriksson: I'm sorry, I made a stupid mistake: to "flip" around the 45° line, you need to subtract from `90`, not from `45`! I've corrected my answer now.

Comment: And now i finally managed to correct the last glitches... Seems to be working now, as long as i keep some cap on the calculation times on my regular fast desktop PC the movement updates now seems to check out. Marking this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

[@ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696490/2410359) and @user3386109  well discuss the issues about angle units and phase.

In addtion, for a "smoother way of doing this in C" also consider:

1. Use `round()`, else code will introduce a bias.  (Assuming `_tanks[1].x` is some integer)

   ```
   double radians = _tanks[0].rotationAngle * (M_PI / 180);
   _tanks[0].x += (int) round(_tanks[0].speed * cos(radians));
   ```
2. Use `float` rather than `double` as the extra precision with its longer calculation time are not needed.

   ```
   float radians = _tanks[0].rotationAngle * (float)((M_PI / 180));
   _tanks[0].x += (int) roundf(_tanks[0].speed * cosf(radians));  // note function names
   ```
3. If processing time is limited, an integer look-up-table could be used with 360 `int` scaled sine and cosine values rather than all the floating point math.

   ```
   _tanks[0].x += (_tanks[0].speed * LUT_cos[_tanks[0].rotationAngle])/scale;
   ```

Comment: As soon as i get the base working i will look into this. The processing time is indeed quite limited, not in the simulation i'm writing but later, on the actual HW. The lookup idea seems like a nice trade off.

Comment: Knowing details like the range of `.speed`, `.x` and `.rotationAngle` will help.  Suggest posting them.

Comment: Range of speed (movement distance per step, velocity) is 0-4 units on the playfield. 

Ranges of X,Y is 800x600 with no negatives in the computer simulation part (0,0 point of origin is top left corner of simulated playfield)

Rotation angle is a full circle in range, 0 to 360 

No decimals are used in the actual step code as the hw later on, will lack support for it (servo controller units). They have support for 32 bit integers however